# Spring Security lgoin always redirecting to authentication failure URL

Tags: java, jsp, spring-security

I am rather new to programming so please help me out a bit here.

I have configured `Spring Security` to fetch user details from the database and when I try to login with the following accounts:

- user1 - password1
- admin - password1

The authentication fails as it always redirect me to `home.jsp/OPS=999` which is my login page. The user record exists in the database but I cannot seem to log in.

This is my security config xml file.

```
 <http auto-config="true">
     <form-login login-page='/home.jsp?OPS=9999' default-target-url='/secure/user.jsp' always-use-default-target='true' />
     <logout logout-success-url="/home.jsp" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
 </http>

<authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="Application.DataSource2" users-by-username-query="select USERNAME, PASSWORD from USER where lower(USERNAME) = lower(?)"/>
</authentication-provider>
```

I am doing it without the authentication/authorities for now as the login is not working. What could be some of the possible reasons for the authentication failure? could database connection play a part? please help me out.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have a look on this http://www.tutorialsdesk.com/2016/02/spring-mvc-security-with-jdbc-database.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realised that the users-by-username-query in the applicationContext-security xml file was missing a enabled column, basically spring security expects 3 columns from the statement and i was missing the enabled column.

so the correct sql statement should be:
"select USERNAME, PASSWORD, STATUS from USER where lower(USERNAME) = lower(?)"

status column is of type boolean. (1=enabled, 0=disabled)

Hope it will help someone out there :)

Thanks for all the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add another `intercept-url`. And it should look like this below:

```
<http auto-config="true" 
      use-expressions="true"
      disable-url-rewriting="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/home.jsp**" access="isAnonymous()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/extreme/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_OPERATOR')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/secure/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <form-login login-page='/home.jsp?OPS=9999' default-target-url='/secure/user.jsp' always-use-default-target='true' />
    <logout logout-success-url="/home.jsp" logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" />
</http>
```

Comment: Hi Yuri! Thank you for your reply! I have tried your suggestion but sadly it results in an error. Is there anyway to debug to find out if it's something to do with the login credentials or the authorities for the user?

Comment: I am using eclipse btw

Comment: I see "Unsupported configuration attributes: [hasRole('ROLE_OPERATOR'), isAnonymous(), isAuthenticated(), hasRole('ROLE_USER')]"

Comment: Did you set in `http` tag `use-expressions="true"`? It is in the code snippet above.

Comment: this error is thrown instead.. "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'use-expressions' is not allowed to appear in element 'http'."

Comment: could it be the version of my spring security? would i need to create a pom.xml file? that was one of the solutions i came across on stackoverflow..

Comment: I think that you need an example to understand that fully. Because we are missing something here :) I would recommend to pick one from here http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/ and also my example from github (I'm using there the latest version of Spring Security): https://github.com/ykushch/spring-sec

Comment: thanks for the references! i am still unable to solve the problem. Could it be the version of spring security im using is too outdated or something? I am using spring security 2.0.4 V

Comment: That's pretty old version. If you can - you should update it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting authentication provider to authentication manager by creating a bean like..

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
    <property name="usersByUsernameQuery" value="select USERNAME, PASSWORD, 1 from USER where lower(USERNAME) = lower(?)"/>
    <property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery" value="SELECT USERNAME, ROLE as authorities FROM USER u, USER_ROLE ur, ROLE r WHERE u.ID = ur.USER_ID AND ur.ROLE_ID = r.ID AND lower(USERNAME) = lower(?)" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="Application.DataSource2" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Hi Karthik! thank you for your reply. I have tried that but it doesn't work. I may have placed it in the wrong place though.. I am suppose to put in between this beans tag? "<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schem ..."

Comment: yes. you are right. inside <beans:beans ..> and after the security config tag <http ...>. In other words remove your <authentication-provider>..</authentication-provider> and add the given code instead of that.

Comment: I have tried that but i came across this error... "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'authentication-manager' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty."

Comment: my opening tag for <authentication-manager> is now <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">

Comment: Take a look at [Spring Forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/70942-no-authenticationprovider-found-after-upgrade-to-spring-security-3-0m2?p=466400#post466400). It might help.